# Load image failed when URL contains symbol '&'

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I used `UniversalImageLoader` in android project, It unable to load image when the URL contains symbol '&', and I replace all the symbol "&" to the "%26", it doesn't work.
The URL like this:

```
http://baike.baidu.com/picture/71563/71563/0/10dfa9ec8a136327e14f5154938fa0ec08fac733#
aid=0&pic=10dfa9ec8a136327e14f5154938fa0ec08fac733
```

Comment: We need to see the code you are using. When I attempt to fetch with `wget`, I can only get a web page (HTML). So you need to explain what "doesn't work" means. Did the API fail, or did you get a 404? Or did something else happen?

Comment: http://d.hiphotos.baidu.com/baike/c0%3Dbaike150%2C5%2C5%2C150%2C50%3Bt%3Dgif/sign=5aac6ec2d343ad4bb2234e92e36b31ca/10dfa9ec8a136327e14f5154938fa0ec08fac733.jpg Try out this one

Comment: Try to replace & with &amp;

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the "&". You can't fetch that picture with UniversalImageLoader because the URL you used is wrong. It's a HTML page URL, no the image Url. In fact the URL of the Image that you want to fetch is:

http://d.hiphotos.baidu.com/baike/c0%3Dbaike150%2C5%2C5%2C150%2C50%3Bt%3Dgif/sign=5aac6ec2d343ad4bb2234e92e36b31ca/10dfa9ec8a136327e14f5154938fa0ec08fac733.jpg

You can right click on that picture and copy its URL to see.

Comment: Think you for your answer.